# How to change polygon colors to white when plotting a shapefile with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, aesthetics, geom-sf

I want to plot the polygons of this shapefile without the colors (just white with black borders); I also do not want the legend. I have tried scale_fill_manual and a few other things but to no avail. I would also like to include the labels (i.e. 901, 902 ....943) within each polygon. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
statsf2134 %>%
 ggplot()+
  geom_sf(aes(fill=Statistica, border = "black"))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Try `geom_sf(fill='white', border = "black")`, without `aes()`.

Comment: As for adding text labels directly on to the map, the *ggsflabel* package might make this much easier than doing it manually. https://yutannihilation.github.io/ggsflabel/reference/geom_sf_label.html

Comment: Just one small detail...how do I remove the letters X and Y from the x and y axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already suggested by @jdobres in the comments set your desired fill color as a parameter outside of `aes()` instead of mapping a variable on the `fill` aesthetic inside `aes()`. Also note that, there is no `border` aesthetic or parameter. If you want to switch the border color use the `color=` parameter. Finally, you could add labels at the center of each polygon using `geom_sf_text`.

Using some fake example data based on the default example from `?geom_sf`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Example data
statsf2134 <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
statsf2134$Statistica <- substr(statsf2134$FIPS, 3, 5)

ggplot(statsf2134) +
  geom_sf(fill = "white") +
  geom_sf_text(
    aes(label = Statistica),
    size = 6 / .pt
  )
#> Warning in st_point_on_surface.sfc(sf::st_zm(x)): st_point_on_surface may not
#> give correct results for longitude/latitude data
```

[image]

Comment: Just one small detail...how do I remove the letters X and Y from the x and y axis?

Comment: Just add `labs(x = "", y="")` or if you want to completely remove the label margin `labs(x = NULL, y=NULL)`.

Comment: statsf2134=st_transform(statsf, 2134)#check if NZ2000 is better
stats<-statsf2134 %>%
 ggplot()+
  geom_sf(fill= 'White')+
  geom_sf_text(
    aes(label = Statistica),
    size = 4 / .pt
  )
stats

Comment: Sorry but where in the chunk above would that go?

Comment: Try `ggplot()+ geom_sf(fill= 'White')+ geom_sf_text( aes(label = Statistica), size = 4 / .pt ) + labs(x = NULL, y=NULL)`